# Init a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following generator function which adds two numbers:

```
def add():
    while True:
        x = yield "x="
        y = yield "y="
        print (x+y)
```

And I can call it like this:

```
x=add()
next(x)
'x='
x.send(2)
'y='
x.send(3)
# 5
```

I thought it would be trivial to add in an `init` so that I don't have to do the `next` and I can just start sending it values, and so I did:

```
def init(_func):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        x=_func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(x)
        return x
    return func
```

Or, simplifying it to receive no input variables like the function above:

```
def init(func):
    x=func()
    next(x)
    return x
```

I thought that doing:

```
x=init(add) # doesn't print the "x=" line.
x.send(2)
'y='
x.send(3)
5
```

Would work, but it seems it acts just like as if the `init` is not there at all. Why does this occur, and how can I get rid of that behavior?

Comment: Maybe look at how `map()` works.

Comment: Both of your example `init` functions work correctly for me on Python 3.7.7. What behavior are you seeing when running them?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo oh, you're right. Actually it's the `x=` 'print' statement that is skipped. Let me post a more thorough output.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo updated the output in the question.

Comment: You never actually print anything: the repl is normally configured to echo the value of non-None expressions. You need to call `print` to print outside the repl.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, thank you that was the issue I was having (I posted an answer too with exactly that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as-is, however, if you want to print the output that occurs **before** the field yield statement, then you can adapt the `init` method to do just that. For example:

```
def init(func):
    x=func()
    a=next(x)
    if a: print (a) # this line will print the output, in your case 'x='
    return x
```

And now you have:

```
>>> x=init(add)
x=
>>> x.send(2)
'y='
>>> x.send(3)
5
```

And finally, to keep your more generalized approach, you can do something like the following with a decorator:

```
def init_coroutine(_func):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        x=_func(*args, **kwargs)
        _ = next(x)
        if _: print (_)
        return x
    return func

@init_coroutine
def add():
    while True:
        x = yield "x="
        y = yield "y="
        print (x+y)


>>> x=add()
x=
>>> x.send(2)
'y='
>>> x.send(3)
5
```

Comment: I'd suggest printing directly in the generator and yielding nothing. Why this awkward construction in the first place?

Comment: The decorator is a good idea. But why using _ as variable name. This always leaves the impression that _ has some language specific meaning (like in Matlab).

Comment: @MadPhysicist really I was just playing around with generators and how they related to call/cc in lisp.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: `_` is usually used for a dummy variable that won't be referenced, e.g. `[somefunc() for _ in range(n)]`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me. Tried

```
def add():
    while True:
        x = yield 'x='
        y = yield 'y='
        print (x+y)
        
def init(func):
    x=func()
    next(x)
    return x

a = init(add)
a.send(5)
a.send(10)
```

For me this returns `15`, as expected.

[update]
After your update, I think you might just want to print out the `a.send()`:

```
def add():
    while True:
        x = yield 'x='
        y = yield 'y='
        print (x+y)
        
def init(func):
    x=func()
    print(next(x))
    return x

a = init(add)
print(a.send(5))
a.send(10)
```